# django registration change language

Tags: django, translation, django-i18n

I'm using django registration and I want to translate the names of the fields and the error messages. I've realized that in /registration/locale there are files with different translations, but I don't how to use them.

This is a template example:

```
<table class="formulari">
<form method='post' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' value="Actualitzar contrassenya" /></td>
</form>
</table>
```

I've tried with:

```
<form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}             
    <tr>
        <th> <label> Contrassenya nova </label> </th>
    <td> {{form.new_password1}} <td>
```

Now I can control the labels values, but I don't know how to translate the errors...

Thanks for your answers and your patience!

Answer (score 1):

1. On top of the template add `{% load i18n %}`.
2. Replace all text labels with their counterparts that exits in english locale file.
3. Wrap all bare text (labels) into `{% trans '<text goes here>' %}`

This should mark those labels for translation. Refer to [django i18n documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here how to use language files within django. You will have to create and compile them.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#message-files